How to count the number of specified words in a document's code (LuaLaTeX)
I think I saw an example of LuaLatex with iterating through all the lines of the source document.
I need to count the number of lines \putf{|P07SP|P09SP|P12SP|} that contain the value from the command \layer -> |P07SP| and insert it into the document. How to do this in LuaLaTeX?
MWE:
% !TeX program = lualatex
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{outdoorunit-7.tex}
% |P07SP|P09SP|P12SP|
example-image-a
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{outdoorunit-5.tex}
% |P18SP|
example-image-b
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{outdoorunit-6.tex}
% |P24SP|
example-image-c
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
totf = 0
str = ""
cpf = 0
function printtexfile (curr, all, file) 
    if string.find(all, curr) then
        for line in io.lines(file) do
            tex.print(line)
        end
    end
end
\end{luacode*}
\makeatletter
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
%========================================
\newcommand{\putf}[2]{%
\directlua{printtexfile(\luastring{\layer},\luastring{#1},\luastring{#2})}%
}
%========================================
% |P07SP|P09SP|P12SP|P18SP|P24SP|
\newcommand{\layer}{|P07SP|}
%\newcommand{\layer}{|P09SP|}
%\newcommand{\layer}{|P12SP|}
%\newcommand{\layer}{|P18SP|}
%\newcommand{\layer}{|P24SP|}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
layer~--~\layer.

1.~\putf{|P07SP|P09SP|P12SP|}{outdoorunit-7.tex}\putf{|P18SP|}{outdoorunit-5.tex}\putf{|P24SP|}{outdoorunit-6.tex} \qquad 2.~\putf{|P07SP|P09SP|P12SP|}{outdoorunit-7.tex}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|C{6cm}|}
    \hline
    Test & 3.~\putf{|P07SP|P09SP|P12SP|}{outdoorunit-7.tex}\putf{|P18SP|}{outdoorunit-5.tex}\putf{|P24SP|}{outdoorunit-6.tex} \\
    \hline
    Test &
    4.~\putf{|P07SP|P09SP|P12SP|}{outdoorunit-7.tex}\putf{|P18SP|}{outdoorunit-5.tex}\putf{|P24SP|}{outdoorunit-6.tex} \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}

\begin{center}  
    5.\\    
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{\putf{|P07SP| P09SP|P12SP|}{outdoorunit-7.tex}\putf{|P18SP|}{outdoorunit-5.tex}\putf{|P24SP|}{outdoorunit-6.tex}} 
\end{center}

6.~\putf{|P07SP|P09SP|P12SP|}{outdoorunit-7.tex}\putf{|P18SP|}{outdoorunit-5.tex}\putf{|P24SP|}{outdoorunit-6.tex}
\end{document}

Example with six occurrences:


\begin{luacode*}

t = 0
local layer = "|P07SP|"

function printtexfile(curr, all, file)
  if string.find(all, curr) then
    for line in io.lines(file) do
      tex.print(line)
    end
  end
end

function mycount(s)
  local matches = {}
  local count = 0
  local s_before_percent = s:match("^(.-)%%") or s:match("^(.-)$")

  if s_before_percent then
    texio.write_nl("PUTF IS FOUND")
    
    s_before_percent, count = s_before_percent:gsub("putf%{(.-)%}", function(match)
      if string.find(match, layer) then
        t = t + 1  -- Предполагаю, что t – это глобальная переменная
      else
        return match
      end
      return ""
    end)
    
    --s = s_before_percent .. s:sub(#s_before_percent + 1)
  end

  texio.write_nl("Строка до процента: " .. s_before_percent)
  texio.write_nl("Количество найденных 'putf': " .. count)

  return s
end
\end{luacode*}


\AtBeginDocument{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer", mycount, "mycount")}}

